# Django N+1 select issue with django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, foreign-keys, django-filter

I have a model (`SpecimenRecord`) with a large number of fields, and I use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to 
create a custom filter for my template. However, `SpecimenRecord` has numerous foreign 
key relationships, and I'm running into Django's N+1 select issue.
As I continue adding objects to the database, the pageload becomes longer.

I understand that using `select_related` can solve this issue, 
but because I'm using django-filter, I'm not sure how to incorporate these solutions
into my `filters.py` file. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my (heavily abbreviated) `filters.py` file:

```
from .models import SpecimenRecord
from django import forms
import django_filters

class SpecimenRecordFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    locality = django_filters.CharFilter(
              field_name='locality__locality_name',
              lookup_expr='icontains',
              label='Locality'
          )
    collector = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
              queryset=Collector.objects.all(),

              """
              Note: using 'SpecimenRecord.objects.prefetch_related('collector').all()' instead
              of what I have above does not yield the appropriate results in my template; I get
              a list of specimen record ids instead of the actual collectors' names
              """

              widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
          )
    # 15 other fields with foreign key relationships were removed for the sake of brevity

    class Meta:
        model = SpecimenRecord
        fields = ['locality', 'collector']
```

**EDIT 1:**
Using [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I discovered that loading my page queried my database 44 times, with 42 similar queries and 39 duplicates. I made the following changes to my views.py and urls.py, and I cut the queries made down to 15, with 12 similar and 12 duplicates. While this is a major improvement, any insights into cutting down the queries further would be greatly appreciated:

`views.py`

```
# This is what I had before
"""
class SpecimenRecordView(generic.ListView):
    model = SpecimenRecordFilter
    template_name = 'database/templates/database/specimenrecord_filter.html'
"""
# Below is the new code

def specimen_filter(request):

    # Again, numerous .select_related queries were removed here for the sake of brevity

    f = SpecimenRecordFilter(request.GET, queryset = SpecimenRecord.objects\
                                    .select_related('locality')\
                                    .prefetch_related('collector').all())
    return render(request, 'database/specimenrecord_filter.html', {'filter': f})
```

And my `urls.py`

```
# Before
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('specimen-records/', FilterView.as_view(filterset_class=SpecimenRecordFilter), name='specimen-records'),
    ...
]

# After
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('specimen-records/', views.specimen_filter, name='specimen-records'),
    ...
]
```

**EDIT 2**
Okay, modifying my `filters.py` (adding filters I was missing for some fields), I'm now down to 5 queries, with only 2 similar and 2 duplicates. The problem is with the many to many relationship I have. What can I do to improve the efficiency of this query?

My `filters.py`:

```
class SpecimenRecordFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    collector = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Collector.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = SpecimenRecord
        fields = [..., 'collector', ...]
```

My `views.py`:

```
def specimen_filter(request):
    f = SpecimenRecordFilter(request.GET, queryset = SpecimenRecord.objects.prefetch_related('collector').all())
    return render(request, 'database/specimenrecord_filter.html', {'filter': f})
```

And my template:

```
...
<div id="form-collector-box">
    <div id="form-collector">
        {{ filter.form.collector.label_tag }}
        <div>
            {% for choice in filter.form.collector %}
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    {{ choice.tag }} {{ choice.choice_label }}
                </label>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
{% for specimenrecord in filter.qs %}
...
    <div class="flex-row tenth collector">{{ specimenrecord.display_collector }}</div>
...
{% endfor %}
```